# Difference between "a crowd" and "crowds"

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Please let me know the difference between *a crowd* and *crowds*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Crowd* refers to a large group of people. Its plural *crowds* refers to large groups of people. For example,

> There was a crowd in the east yesterday.
>
> There were crowds in the east and west yesterday.

Comment: Read technically, yes. But idiomatically, "crowds" can also just refer to one very large group of people.

Comment: @SamuelLijin I think *crowds* are more likely more than one crowd, since crowds are groups and by definition have bounderies or limits. I suppose its possible that *crowds* could be used as you say, but it would be helpful if you wrote an answer with some sources using it that way.

Comment: this is like the fish and fishes question. A fish, Many fish (of same species), many fishes (different species). 

similarly, a crowd (in a single location or of single species), many crowds (multiple locations or multiple species)